# Oracle APEX - Obligation to upgrade in future?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

Have a theoretical question - assuming I download Oracle Apex 20.2 for a local install how long could I run this version without upgrading?

Obviously there'll be performance enhancements and additional features included in newer releases, but could it run uninterrupted *indefinitely* without being forced to upgrade?

Information on oracle docs shows 45 days to defer on upgrades using their ATP, however no real source of information for on premise installs.

Also this question is parking aside any security elements.

Thanks.

Comment: in a managed cloud environment, you can defer an APEX upgrade, but eventually you'll have to allow the upgrade - it's a MANAGED service after all. For your own installs, you can run them for as long as you want. You may just be running a version that's no longer supported. We have customers running ANCIENT versions of APEX, and seem to be 'ok'

Comment: we have frequent updates and security is taken seriously, if a security vulnerability is discovered, we will path/fix them ASAP, and it's on you to uptake those fixes/patches...these are very rare for APEX, it's more likely something in the stack has a known vulnerability in a 3rd party library for example.

Comment: also, i know customers who are running versions 9 and 10 of the database still and those are decades old...you CAN do things, even if you SHOULD NOT do them

Comment: Appreciate the heads up, delving into the framework and possible development of applications for on premise use, though did want to know the "life" of the application aside from variables such as security which would need immediate attention. Also was curious to see if any post-production support would be required for simple apps if not planned for/or even requested.